# UITableViewCell filling with another cell contents

Tags: ios, uitableview, drawing

I make my `UITableViewCell` wait before I call `drawRect:`, as some background process takes place. In that time, it fills the cell with another cell's contents. I don't want it to do that though, I want it to appear empty. How do I stop this behaviour?

Comment: In this and your previous question, you're talking about doing things to/in `drawRect:` that you shouldn't be doing. When UIKit sends `drawRect:` to your view, you need to draw whatever you can immediately and as fast as possible, then return control. You can always re-draw later when you have more information about the contents that should be displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of making drawRect wait, call it but have it draw what you want there while it is loading (empty areas, loading..., etc) and then call it again to draw what is needed when you have the data.